# How to link arm_cortexM4l_math.lib in Openstm32

Tags: c, fft, cortex-m, cmsis

I've included CMSIS_5 library, but I don't know how to link arm_cortexM4l_math.lib to my stm32 project for FFT.

My board is stm32f407-DISCOVERY and I'm using Openstm32.

Comment: -lm CMSIS as I know does not link to anything

Comment: i need use CMSIS_5 and link this lib file because, I'm getting  error like this (when I'm using oryginal CMSIS):

,, undefined reference to ' arm_cfft_radix4_init_f32 ' "

Comment: It is a part of the CMSIS and is not in any library.  You should add the apriopriate .c file to the project. For example https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/master/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_cfft_radix4_init_f32.c

Comment: I'm trying to link entire library because adding individual .c files causes more errors such as: (after adding arm_cfft_radix4_init_f32.c)

,, undefined reference to 'arm_bitreversal_f32'

over and over again..
I know that in CooCox IDE it's enough to link that single file, but I'm using openstm32 under linux.

Comment: you need the complete set of files https://github.com/diymat/CMSIS_DSP

Comment: Which files contain the definitions uint16_t and uint32_t? because eclipse say unresolved error

Comment: shame - asking about DSP and not knowing the basics :) <stdint.h>

Comment: Still not work..  unresovleds : 
  S->pTwiddle
  S->twidCoefModifier
  S->bitRevFactor
  S->pBitRevTable
  S->onebyfftLen
and more and more similar errors

Comment: Import an example project from the the cube. Remove custom files and go ahead. I do not have any problems with it. You make a mistake when you create the project on openstm

Comment: I only create project used Project C -> Ac6 STM32 MCU Project 
Toolchains Ac6 STM32 MCU GCC  -> Select my stm32f407 board 
-> Standard Periphal Library (StdPeriph) -> finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was resolved in a few simple steps.

I noticed that when I create a project, I can choose to export options for separated directory of standard stm32 peripherals.

1. Select export to a separate directory of standard stm32 libraries. (When I chose this solution, showed two folders next to my project: `stm32f407_stdperiph_lib` and `STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.8.0`)
2. `stm32f407_stdperiph_lib` was linked immediately after the project was created.
3. `STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.8.0` - This library is only added next to my project directory, but wasn't linked
4. Link to `STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.8.0`:
5. In `Properties` → `Settings` → `MCCC GCC Compiler` → `Includes`
6. I added:

   ```
   "$ {Workspace_loc: /STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.8.0/Libraries/CMSIS  /Device/ST/STM32F4xx/}
   "$ {Workspace_loc: /STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.8.0/}"
   "$ {Workspace_loc: /STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.8.0/Libraries/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/}"
   ```
7. Add preprocessor in MCCC GCC Compiler:

   - In `Properties` → `Settings` → `MCCC GCC Compiler` →  `Preprocessor`

add `ARM_MATH_CM4`

10. Copy the whole `Source` directory from `DSP_Lib` to the `src` directory of the project
11. Build